# A Problem involving simple mathematical induction.

Tags: induction

$6^n-5n+4$ is divisible by $5 \;$ for all natural numbers $n$.

what I did is:

IA

$A(1):\;6^1-5\cdot1+4=5$ which is true.

IS

$A(n):\; 6^n+5n+4$ is also divisible by $5$.

Show $A(n+1)$ is divisible by $5$

$$A(n+1): \;
 6^{n+1}-5(n+1)+4=6^n\cdot 6-5n-5+4$$  After this step I want to get to $A(n)$ but how?

please give tips to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $A(n+1) = 6\cdot 6^n - 5n-5+4 = 5\cdot 6^n + 6^n - 5n - 5 + 4$. But $5\cdot 6^n$ and $-5$ are both divisible by $5$, so $A(n+1)$ is divisible by $5$ if and only if the other terms are; those terms are $6^n - 5n + 4 = A(n)$.

An alternate way of approaching this problem is directly, using the binomial theorem:
$$6^n - 5n + 4 = (5+1)^n - 5n + 4.$$
Every term in the expansion of $(5+1)^n$ except for the final term is divisible by $5$, and $-5n$ is divisible by $5$. So the leftover terms are $1+4=5$, which is also divisible by $5$.

Comment: thnks a ton. really apreciate alternate ways!

Comment: hey roger can i ask u a question? how do i write maths like you ? i mean type on this website like your answer.

Comment: @Sash Look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing math. For general information about how to format posts using HTML markdown, when you start typing a question or an answer, there's a yellow-orange question mark at the upper right corner of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternate method:

The right-most digit of $6^n$ is $6$

Adding $4$ gives a right-most digit of $0$;  this new number is divisible by $5$

Subtracting $5n$, a number divisible by $5$, produces a number divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way
is to look at the difference between
consecutive terms
(this is what is needed
for an induction proof):

$(6^{n+1}-5(n+1)+4)
-(6^n-5n+4)
=(6^{n+1}-6^n)-5
=6^n(6-1)+5
=5(6^n-1)
$
so the difference between
consecutive terms
is always divisible by $5$.

Since the first term
is divisible by $5$,
all the terms are.